# How to take advantage of multi-cpu in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cpu, cpu-usage

I work in lab and wrote multithreaded computational program, on C++11 using `std::thread`. Now I have an opportunity to run my program on multi-cpu server.

Server:

- Runs Ubuntu server
- Has 40 Intel CPU's

I know nothing about multi-cpu programming. First idea, that comes into my mind to run 40 applications and then glue their results together. It is possible, but I want to know more about my opportunities.

1. If I compile my code on server by it's gcc compiler, does resulting application take advantage of multi-cpu?
2. If #1 answer depends, how can I check it?

Thank you!

Comment: If your program has multiple threads already then the OS will automatically schedule those threads on different CPUs. You'll be limited by the number of threads. If you create 10 threads then your program will be limited to at most 10 CPUs.

Comment: If each "result" is completely independent of all others, i would actually write a single thread application, and then execute it via `parallel` (see `sudo apt-get install parallel; man parallel`)

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on SO. I have removed your subquestions about libraries and other resources, as the rest of the question is salvagable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not only about multi-thread, but about multi-cpu.

1. Basically the operating system will automatically spread out the threads over the cores. You don't need to do anything.
2. Once you are using C++11, you have `std::thread::get_id()` that you can call and identify the different thread, but you CAN NOT identify the core you are using. Use `pthreads` directly + "cpu affinity" for this.

You can google for "CPU affinity" for more details on how to get control over it. If you want this kind of precision. You can identify the core as well as choose the core... You can start with this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html

Comment: This answer seems to have nothing to do with the question. The questioner has no apparent need for core or thread affinity, which is basically all you discuss.

Comment: Ah, the puppy beat me to it. OP is asking how to multithread, not how to bind threads to cores. In most throughput-oriented apps, you don't care where the threads are running.

Comment: He is not only asking about multi-thread, but also multi-cpu. it's a lilttle different.... and he wants to check for it. It means he needs a lower level code to check multi-cpu.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota You don't need lower level code to use multiple CPUs. All you need to do is spawn N threads and the OS will distribute it over N cores for you. Unless we're talking about MPI, but that's a different story.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota It is nice answer, thank you. I'm mostly intereseted in multi-cpu.

Comment: lol, yes, again, you need lower level stuff to answer the question 2... I just answered your question. I don't know WHY you want to check it. But if you want to check, you need the things I wrote.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota From the HPC world? I think everyone is comment on the scope of the question, not the validity of your answer. You answered a question he's likely to have next if he's optimizing a multi-threaded application on a high core count system and that is performance sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

If your program runs multithreaded your OS should take care automatically that it uses the CPUs available.

Make sure to distribute the work you have to do to about the same number of threads there are CPUs you can use. Make sure it is not just one thread that does the work and the other threads are just waiting for the termination of this thread.